# Post tweet to a user with Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been using the [**Twitter Oauth API**](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) for posting tweets to my twitter timeline from my php application. It is working well.

```
<?php
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $OAuthToken, $OAuthSecret);
$message = "This is a test message.";
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "$message"));
?>
```

But i would like to know, is there an API that can post tweets to the timeline of my friends (those i am following on twitter) ? Or does the twitter API allow posting of tweets only to the authenticated user's timeline?

Comment: You want to be able to make tweets as if you were someone else? No. You can @mention people though

Comment: Can i get the names of my "following" list on twitter and mention them in my tweets, using the API?

Comment: Why it has been downvoted? Please add a comment instead.

Comment: I feel that it is not possible (and even not legal) to post tweets to a user on behalf of another user, with an API. So i decided to close this question.

Comment: @dskanth:i am stuck at the same thing..i am authentificating a user ..after that the user types a msg and clicks submit..This msg should go to his timeline..but its not going..?I hope you can help me..The tweet irrespective of the user..goes directly to my time line..i want that tweet to be displayed on respective users timeline..how do i do that..i am using the same code that you are using

Comment: @dskanth:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954114/post-tweet-on-users-timeline

Please check this question

Comment: @OPUS I think it is just not possible with Twitter API yet. Refer: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/9574